# How exclude or skip post type with get_next_post_link

Tags: custom-post-types, php, plugin-development, functions

I have a post type called families where I add personal information of each family, inside the data there is an option called status.

*IMPORTANT: The fields are created with ACF CUSTOM FIELDS

[image: status]

These families are shown on one page each. For example

[image: family on site]

What I need is to exclude the families that do not have the status Retained, and that are not shown or linked in the next and back buttons.

[image: next an back]

in my code I have functions get_next_post_link() and get_previous_post_link()

```
<?php
$older_link = get_next_post_link( '%link', '<i class="far fa-angle-right"></i>' );
$newer_link = get_previous_post_link( '%link', '<i class="far fa-angle-left"></i>' );
$previous = '<span class="meta-nav">Previous Post</span>';
$next = '<span class="meta-nav">Next Post</span>';
?>
```

```
<nav class="d-flex align-items-center navigation navigation-single">
    <div class="arrows">
        <?php echo $newer_link; ?>
        <?php echo $older_link; ?>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

What is `Status`? If it's a taxonomy - and, by the look of it, it should be - you can exclude any given term in [get_previous_post_link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_previous_post_link/) using the `$excluded_terms` parameter.

If status is not a taxonomy already, you might want to rethink that for performance reasons.

Comment: The status is a value I take from a custom field named family_status

Comment: i tried this way but don't work 
 $family_id = get_field( 'family_id' );
 $status_family = get_field( 'status' ); 
 if ( $status_family !== 'Retained'){
  $exclude[] = $family_id;
 }
$newer_link = get_previous_post_link( '%link', '<i class="far fa-angle-left"></i>', false, $exclude );
$older_link = get_next_post_link( '%link', '<i class="far fa-angle-right"></i>', false, $exclude );